Wine "zsh: segmentation fault wine programname.exe", but suspicons about invalid file path
I am trying to run Windows program installer on Mac using wine.
I am using commands:
brew install --cask wine-stable
brew install winetricks
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 WINEARCH=win32 winecfg
cd ~/Downloads
Downloads % WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine programname_setup.exe

My wine installation is somehow correct - it gives correct response to wine --help but it gives zsh: segmentation fault  wine programname_setup.exe to both WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine programname_setup.exe and wine programname_setup.exe.
There was suggestion to test command wine notepad and it gave segmentation fault as well.
Call with debug options WINEDEBUG=+all wine programname_setup.exe &> wine_debug.log (and similar variations with win32 configuration) is giving the same error message and no debug logs.
There is strange thing - the error message stays the same, if I am providing some non-existing exe file name, although one could expect that wine should report if there exe file is not found. So - there is this risk, that maybe wine is not reporting non-existant exe file and I am missing some completely minor detail?
My Mac is having sofware with some date around 2021 and I didn't check the exact version of Mac, I am connecting via TeamVier to it.
I have tested the same Windows setup program on Sonoma M2 Mac (via remote connection to the Amazon EC2 cloud) and I managed to run setup program, to install the Windows program and to use it. Wine worked spectacularly well. But I have this segmentation fault on other Mac.
There was suggestion to upgrade wine
brew update
brew upgrade wine

But I didn't do it - why should I upgrade freshly installed brew and wine?
So - maybe someone recognizes such situation and can suggest some debugging, tracing or even some solution? Thx.

I am having the exact same issue, did you end up finding a solution?
Mine outputs the same thing pretty much no matter what I enter.
(base) user@users-MBP ~ % wine help

=
zsh: segmentation fault  wine help

Trying to install steam:
(base) user@users-MBP ~ % wine SteamSetup.exe

=
zsh: segmentation fault  wine SteamSetup.exe


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
